# CSS isn't working with navigator in Java with Vaadin

Tags: java, html, css, netbeans, vaadin

My css seems to be working funny with my vaadin project which implements different views. Basically my login view which is the first view loaded has different page elements such as the layout, a panel and a couple of buttons etc. nested inside of the layout. I used setStyleName to name each individual component and style them the way i wanted to. My problem is, that I've set the whole layout to a style of xx (example) and set the background color. But when I run the project it returns the correct background but the rest of the styling elements for the other components arent rendered. Not sure why?

Here is my CSS:

```css
 .bgstyle1 {
     
/*      background-image: url('http://oi62.tinypic.com/4kczut.jpg');*/
/*      background-image: url("http://oi62.tinypic.com/4kczut.jpg");*/
      background-color: #000064;
      position: relative;
  }
  
  
  .welcomestyle1 {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: “Century Gothic”, CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(236,240,241);
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
  }
  
  .subhead1 {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
      margin-left: 100px !important;
      margin-top: 50px !important;
      font-family: “Century Gothic”, CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif !important;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: lighter;
      color: rgb(236,240,241) !important;
      border: 0px solid !important;
      border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
       box-shadow: none !important;
```

part of my code:

```
 private VerticalLayout buildUI() {
            layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setImmediate(true);
    layout.setSizeFull();
    layout.setStyleName("bgstyle1");


            pnl = buildpnl();
            welcome = new Label();
            welcome.setValue("Welcome to travel");
    welcome.setStyleName("welcomestyle1");
    welcome.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This is just some of my css

Comment: Can you please inspect the rendered element in your navigator and show us the HTML rendered?